# Pivot longer - spliting column by first and last underscore in R

Tags: r, pivot

I want to pivot a dataset like this to long, splitting the column into three 1) before the first underscore 2) after the last underscore and 3) everything in between.

I have a dataframe like this

```
amino_acid_change <- c("Arg2Trp", "Asp40Glu", "Asp8Asn")
col_1 <- c(13582, 5960, 3371)
col_2 <- c(12589, 7531, 3083)

df <- tibble(amino_acid_change, col_1, col_2)
df <- df %>% 
  rename("0_BDQ_1" = col_1,
         "0_BDQ_PZA_1" = col_2)

df
```

and I want to pivot to long, retaining the 'amino_acid_change' column and splitting the others as above. Of course it is the regex for names_pattern that I'm finding difficult.

This is the basic code, but without the regex.

```
df_long <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(!amino_acid_change,
               names_to = c("time", "arm", "replicate"), 
               names_pattern = "(...)(...)(...)",
               values_to = "count")
```

Desired output

```
A tibble: 6 x 5
  amino_acid_change  time arm     replicate count
  <chr>             <dbl> <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>
1 Arg2Trp               0 BDQ             1 13582
2 Asp40Glu              0 BDQ             1  5960
3 Asp8Asn               0 BDQ             1  3371
4 Arg2Trp               0 BDQ_PZA         1 12589
5 Asp40Glu              0 BDQ_PZA         1  7531
6 Asp8Asn               0 BDQ_PZA         1  3083
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This seems to come close to what you want, but I've had to make some assumptions about the general form of your patterns.

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(!amino_acid_change,
               names_to = c("time", "arm", "replicate"), 
               names_pattern = "^(\\d+)_([A-Z0-9]+_?[A-Z0-9]+)_([0-9]+)$",
               values_to = "count")
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  amino_acid_change time  arm     replicate count
  <chr>             <chr> <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>
1 Arg2Trp           0     BDQ     1         13582
2 Arg2Trp           0     BDQ_PZA 1         12589
3 Asp40Glu          0     BDQ     1          5960
4 Asp40Glu          0     BDQ_PZA 1          7531
5 Asp8Asn           0     BDQ     1          3371
6 Asp8Asn           0     BDQ_PZA 1          3083
```

**Explanation**

Breaking down the regex...

`^(\\d+)`: The `time` starts at the start of the column name and consists of one or more decimal digits.

`_`: An underscore, which does not form part of a capturing group.

`([A-Z0-9]+_?[A-Z0-9]+)`: The `arm`.  It is *at least 2 characters long*.  It starts with a string of at least one decimal digit or uppercase letter.  Then there is an optional (`?`) underscore.  Finally, there is another string of at least one decimal digit or uppercase letter.

`_`: An underscore, which does not form part of a capturing group.

`([0-9]+)$`:  The `replicate` consists of at least one decimal digit and ends at the end of the string.

Comment: Thank you for the response and explanation. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `merge` argument in `separate()` and `extract()` from `tidyr` package:

Here:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -"amino_acid_change",
    names_to = "key",
    values_to = "count"
  ) %>% 
  separate(key, c("time", "arm"), extra = "merge") %>% 
  extract(arm, c("arm", "replicate"), "(.*)_([^_]+)$")
```

Output is:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  amino_acid_change time  arm     replicate count
  <chr>             <chr> <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>
1 Arg2Trp           0     BDQ     1         13582
2 Arg2Trp           0     BDQ_PZA 1         12589
3 Asp40Glu          0     BDQ     1          5960
4 Asp40Glu          0     BDQ_PZA 1          7531
5 Asp8Asn           0     BDQ     1          3371
6 Asp8Asn           0     BDQ_PZA 1          3083
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Using separate() wasn't something I had thought of.